# Can't use lists in dictionaries

Tags: python, list

I got a problem:
I want to save lists in a dictionary like that:

`EventFields: dict = {[0, 1]: 'specialField'}`

Why does this not match? And what's the solution?

Thanks

Comment: You can use tuples instead of lists...so `(0, 1)` instead of `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146. What do you mean by "not match"? What problem are you trying to solve? While I happen to recognize what you are doing (so I could link you to a duplicate), it's important to ask questions clearly and state the actual problem. Developing this skill will also help you find answers with a search engine - whether you search for the [problem](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=TypeError%3A+unhashable+type%3A+%27list%27) or the [goal](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+use+list+as+dict+key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists aren't hashable, since you can mutate a list (e.g. by doing something like `list[0] = 1`).

You would want to cast the list to a tuple:

```
dict = {(0, 1): 'specialField'}
```

Comment: Much easier to just write the tuple directly: `(0, 1)`. Also, Python doesn't really have "casts"; you are creating a new object.

Comment: Fair point -- edited.